# Storing and Retrieving JSON type data between H2 in-memory DB and Spring boot @Entity class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables created in a H2 in-memory DB inside a spring boot app as shown below:

1. **Restaurant Table**

```
CREATE TABLE RESTAURANT (
    ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    BOOKING_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TABLES JSON
);
```

2. **BookTable Table**

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKTABLE (
    TABLE_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    SEATING_CAPACITY INT NOT NULL,
    IS_AVAILABLE BOOL
);
```

My immediate first question here is, how do I insert data in the **Restaurant** Table using SQL Commands (specially the JSON field **"TABLES"** which actually stores the data from the other **BOOKTABLE** table in a JSON format?
Is this query correct?

```
INSERT INTO RESTAURANT VALUES (2, 'Saraya', '2021-05-25', '[{"tableId": 1, "seatingCapacity": 12, "isAvailable": true}]');
```

**NOTE: Im expecting **Restaurant** table to store multiple tables, hence the array in the JSON string.**

Next, I have these two *@Entity* classes defined in my Spring Boot project:

1. **Restaurant.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="BOOKING_DATE")
    private Date bookingDate;

    @Column(name = "TABLES", columnDefinition = "json")
    @JsonRawValue
    private String tables;
}
```

2. **BookTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "booktable")
public class BookTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="TABLE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long tableId;

    @Column(name="SEATING_CAPACITY")
    private int seatingCapacity;

    @Column(name="IS_AVAILABLE")
    private boolean isAvailable;
}
```

I am trying to do basic CRUD Operations on these entities. I have below controller created for my **Restaurant** Entity:

**RestaurantController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/restaurants")
public class RestaurantController {

    private final RestaurantService restaurantService;

    public RestaurantController(RestaurantService restaurantService) {
        this.restaurantService = restaurantService;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public List<Restaurant> getAllExistingRestaurants() {
        return restaurantService.getAllRestaurants();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public Restaurant getRestaurantById(@PathVariable("id") Long reservationId) {
        return restaurantService.getRestaurant(reservationId);
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    private long addRestaurant(@RequestBody Restaurant restaurant) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        restaurantService.AddNewRestaurant(restaurant);
        return restaurant.getId();
    }
}
```

As you can see above, for now i am just trying 3 REST APIs: *GetAll()*, *GetByID()* and *Post()*. Below is the service class code:
**RestaurantService.java**

```
package com.assignment.restaurantmanagement.service;

import com.assignment.restaurantmanagement.model.BookTable;
import com.assignment.restaurantmanagement.model.Restaurant;
import com.assignment.restaurantmanagement.repository.RestaurantRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class RestaurantService {

    private final RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    private final TableService tableService;

    public RestaurantService(RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository, TableService tableService) {
        this.restaurantRepository = restaurantRepository;
        this.tableService = tableService;
    }

    // Retrieve all restaurants
    public List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants() {
        List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();
        restaurantRepository.findAll().forEach(restaurants::add);
        return restaurants;
    }

    // Retrieves a restaurant based on restaurant id
    public Restaurant getRestaurant(Long id) {
        Optional<Restaurant> restaurant = restaurantRepository.findById(id);
        return restaurant.get();
    }

    // Adds a new restaurant
    public void AddNewRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
       //*Some code here*
    }
}
```

And below is the Repository classes defined for each of the Entities:
**RestaurantRepository.java**

```
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Long> {
}
```

**TableRepository.java**

```
public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<BookTable, Long> {
}
```

I have below further questions:

1. How do I add/store multiple **BookTable** objects (*List*) in the column **TABLES** which has data type *JSON* in the **RESTAURANT** table, through the POST API call?
2. How do i read the same JSON column **TABLES** from the **RESTAURANT** table and convert it into *BookTable* object or *List<BookTable* object for the *GetByID()* and *GetAll()* APIs?

Basically, i want to store and retrieve the entire *Restaurant* JAVA object which internally has *BookTable* object as part of its data members through REST APIs with H2 in-memory database. I am open to any new changes in this existing code and table structures.

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing now?
And anything you tried?
"tables" field is just String in your model. You can use ObjectMapper to covert explicitly before sending to database.
That's why i'm saying what is the issue you are facing as of now?

Comment: Didn't quite understand your requirement. What I feel that your looking for a relation between the table Restaurant and BookTable. It could be a one many relation. So for one restaurant table could have a list of booktable objects.